# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1/1/2016' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a date key in my tables, so I wrote this code

```
INSERT INTO [INT].[Budget] (Budget.[Date], Budget.[Sales], Budget.[Margin], Budget.DATEKEY, Stores.[Storekey])
    SELECT 
        Budget.[Date], Budget.[Sales], Budget.[Margin],
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [Date], 112),
        Stores.[Storekey]
    FROM 
        [STG].[CSV_budget] Budget
```

But when I execute it, I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1/1/2016' to data type int

Comment: Column Budget.DATEKEY data type?

Comment: @jarlh it's nvarchar(255)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? The DDL of the tables `[INT].[Budget]`, `[STG].[CSV_budget]` and a *single* row `INSERT`ed into the table `[STG].[CSV_budget]` that causes the error when you `INSERT` it into `[INT].[Budget]` would be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the date column type which was nvarchar because it's from CSV file, I changed it to Date and everything went well.